# How can I share a video file during a webinar?

Tags: video-streaming

Here is the scenario: I have a number of remote employees around the globe. I want to have a video chatting session. No problem there. Halfway through, I want to shut off all camera video feeds and simulcast (synchronous) a training video to my team. How do I do this?

We have tried office communicator, but the frame rate was awful and no audio. Adobe Connect had similar trouble. In both cases we were limited by the main office's small internet pipe, but it is clear that video delivered by shared desktop is not a good solution.